# How to use props.match.params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am passing a videoId from Dashboard to URL path and fetching it in Videoplayer Component using `props.match.params.videoId`. If I use VideoPlayerContainer in App.js route I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` but if I use VideoPlayer component instead of container in App.js route it works and gets the videoId from URL.

Any Idea how to make it work with using VideoPlayerContainer?

App.js

```
function App() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/dashboard"
          component={DashboardContainer}
        />
            <ProtectedRoute
              exact
              path="/videoplayer/:videoId"
              component={VideoPlayerContainer}
            />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

VideoPlayerContainer

```
    export default function VideoPlayerContainer() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <PublicNav />
        <VideoPlayer />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

VideoPlayer

```
    export default function VideoPlayer(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let videoId = props.match.params.videoId;
  const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);
  const [CommentLists, setCommentLists] = useState([]);

  const videoVariable = {
    videoId: videoId,
  };
```

Comment: You need to pass `match` as a prop to your VideoPlayer in VideoPlayerContainer. As of now you are passing nothing to VideoPlayer

Comment: Posted an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `match` param that you are getting through react-router in VideoPlayerContainer to your VideoPlayer component. The below code should work

```
export default function VideoPlayerContainer(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <PublicNav />
        <VideoPlayer match={props.match} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import useParams hook from react router dom like this

```
import {  useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

In your Component

```
 let  { videoId } = useParams();
```

By this you can get url params